# cropped image height and width not getting fixed as 160px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, crop

I have created an application using **[cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)** for cropping an images. The application is working and the image is cropping

I have given a fixed image width and height for the cropped image as 160 option like as given below.

```
$("#getCropped").click(function () {
    $('#croppedImage').html($image.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {
       width: 160,
       height: 160
    }));
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jer3onxu/)**

But the issue is that when I select an area as width and height somewhat equal as the cropped Image, then I am getting the cropped Image height ans width as 160px like as shown below

[image]

but when I select an area where width and height varies in which height is more than width as the cropped Image, then I am not getting cropped Image as height and width as 160px like as shown below

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: cropper.js takes the aspect ratio into account (see function r()), the provided values for height and width are only minimum values. You would need to override switch statements in cropper.js in order to crop the image to your needs.

Comment: override switch statements in cropper.js , like in which way

Comment: I don't see an option to make the final crop square, thus you would need to hack cropper.js itself. Open up cropper.js and look into it. Not the best solution, though. What about just overriding the canvas dimensions with CSS (and overflow: hidden)?

Comment: Just a note: even if you select almost square parts of the original image, the cropped image will not always be 160x160px, but something like 160x176px according to your selection.

Comment: @Paul so you meant to say that if I put an aspect ration, things will work fine

Comment: No, cropper.js is retrieving the aspect ratio from the selection and produces an output according to that. If you just override the aspect ratio itself, you will probably get unexpected results, e.g. stretched images. Just might be, that cropper.js is not the right tool here but then I don't know anything about the application you built.

Comment: I think if you want to fix the height and width of crop-box,then you have to override the function `crop: function (data) {}`  , In the `data` you will find some parameters like(x-axis, y-axis, height, width). So, you need to just put the static value in height and width. Here i put some link for reference..   http://spmjs.io/package/cropper  and   http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/#overview

Comment: actually my real task which I am trying to do is, lets say I am selecting an image and selecting a portion as the cropped image I want that cropped image to be saved in four resolutions as four different image files such as 480x480(smartphone), 650x481(tablet), 1050x651(small desktop), 1290x1051(large desktop)

Comment: Then you need this function...  `$().cropper("getCroppedCanvas")`  , this will do your work. See the live demo here...  http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/#overview

Comment: @Mischievous I have tried that `$image.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {width: 650,height: 481});` for tablet but its not working

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer after several tweaks, this is my solution and it works, i was trying to set the width to 240px and the height to 507px, upon initialization.

```
       var cropper;
       var imgx;

       $(function(){
         var imgx = $('#cpdiv').find('img');
         cropper = new Cropper(imgx[0], {             
                autoCropArea: 0,
                strict: false,
                guides: false,
                highlight: true,
                dragCrop: false,
               //cropBoxMovable: false,
                cropBoxResizable: false,

                data:{
                    width: 160,
                    height: 160,
                },

                crop(event) {
                    console.log(event.detail.width);
                    console.log(event.detail.height);
                },
            });
      });
```

and this worked for me perfectly for me... when you console.log the dimensions it all reflects the exact dimensions as the cropped section.